# Get the date with format on google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using this script to take some information from the below table (this table information is used to send the information by email) and I was getting a huge data format, so I tried to take the day, month and year using the .getDay, `.getMonth()` and `.getFullYear()`, but I'm receiving the error message:

> "Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: email. (line 108, file "Code")"

I imagine that is because I'm using get 3 times inside a loop multiple times, is there a way to take without having this error message? Because I'd like to take the format date as it is on the spreadsheet (Day-shortMonth-year)

I saw about the `Utilities.formatDate()` but I couldn't be able to think a on way to use it.

[image: screenshot of relevant range]

Here is a part of the script, I didn't put everything cause is a little bit big script, but let me know if you need and I edit and put everything.

```
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let rows = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var emailRecipients = rows[1][0]+"@gmail.com";
  var CCemail = rows[1][1]+"@gmail.com";
  var emailSubject = "Vacation Request";
for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let bg_color;
    switch(rows[i][5]) {
        case 'Reflected':
              bg_color = 'green';
              break;
        case 'Cancelled':
              bg_color = 'Darkred';
              break;
        case 'Pending':
              bg_color = 'orange';
              break;
        case 'Rejected':
              bg_color = 'red';
              break;
        default:
              bg_color = 'white';
    }
    htmlBody += `   
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;border:none">
       <colgroup>
              <col width="100">
              <col width="100">
              <col width="100">
              <col width="100">
       </colgroup>
       <tbody>  
          <tr style="height:21px">
            <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">
            ${rows[i][2].getDate()+"-"+rows[i][2].getMonth()+"-"+rows[i][2].getFullYear()}
          <\/td>
            <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">
            ${rows[i][3]}
          <\/td>
            <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">
            ${rows[i][4]}
          <\/td>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:${bg_color};font-weight:bold;color:rgb(255,255,255);text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">  
            ${rows[i][5]}
          <\/td>
        <\/tr>
     <\/table>`;
```

The line 108 is:

> "MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailRecipients,subject: emailSubject,htmlBody: htmlBody,cc: CCemail})"

Comment: When you figure what line is causing the problem let us know perhaps we can help.

Comment: Yes, an edit is definitely needed - the part of the script that causes the issue is not the part you published. As the error clearly states, you exceeded the quota, most likely for sending emails in one day

Comment: I added the line 108, where was retrieving the error!

Comment: Yep, [quota issue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) alright - you will have to wait until it replenishes (24 hours appx, but the window in which it happens is unknown)

Comment: Great, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding something like this into your loop so you wont get this problem any more.

```
if(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()>0){
   MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailRecipients,subject: emailSubject,htmlBody: htmlBody,cc: CCemail})
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper!!! Other doubt, is there a way to change the part with month date to take "Jan, Fev,..."?

Comment: I don't understand you additional question.

Comment: I asked about this line: "${rows[i][2].getDate()+"-"+rows[i][2].getMonth()+"-"+rows[i][2].getFullYear()}" where for the [getMonth] returns to me the number of the month, not the name, do you have any advice in how can I do it? Cause I search but I think I'm searching on the wrong way

Comment: const mA=["Jan","Feb","Mar",....];  ${rows[i][2].getDate()+"-"+mA[rows[i][2].getMonth()]+"-"+rows[i][2].getFullYear()}